# How to detach modal dialogs from main window? Popup dialogs attached to window title and not movable

Tags: gnome, dialog

Not sure of the terminology here, but most of my popup dialogs (see screenshot below) are attached to the window title and cannot be moved. If the parent window is moved, the popup moves with it. Is there a way to get rid of this and have all popup dialogs be opened as movable windows?

[image: screenshot with GNOME]

Ubuntu 17.10+ with GNOME Shell

[image: screenshot with ginnamon]

Ubuntu 11.10 with Cinnamon

Comment: BTW FYI the correct terminology here would be a "modal dialog". That's also how it is (correctly) called in the GNOME tweak tool, see [my answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/836137/606016).

Comment: I had the "opposite" problem in a way. I modal dialog pops up and to answer it correctly I need to see something that's below it. Trying to move the dialog, the parent window would just follow along. Putting this here in case someone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 47):

I found a much easier solution. Actually you can configure it with the [GNOME Tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Tweaks) (previously known as "GNOME Tweak Tool"):
[image: "Attached model dialogs" under "Windows" disabled]

Just disable "Attached modal dialogs" under "Windows".

Comment: This should be the accepted answer at this time.

Comment: This has been bugging me for months in Debian 9... such an easy fix!

Comment: why this is still enabled by default in 20.04 ubuntu? what a genius invented this feature ...

Comment: @madzohan: Didn't you hear? Giving users too much flexibility scares them away! So say a lot of today's UX designers, anyhow. I say, when done properly, flexibility makes software better and easier for more users.

Answer (score 21):

Just for those that was unable to solve this, here is what I did to make my dialogs moveable.

I used dconf-editor which can be easily installed by: `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`

1. Open: `dconf-editor`
2. Browse to: **org -> gnome -> shell -> overrides -> attach-modal-dialogs**
3. Set it to: `false`

Or everything in one line without installing dconf-editor:

1. Detach dialog: `dconf write /org/gnome/shell/overrides/attach-modal-dialogs false`
2. Attach dialog: `dconf write /org/gnome/shell/overrides/attach-modal-dialogs true`

Using Ubuntu 12.04 BTW.

Comment: Thank you for this. Upped. Though, I must admit that this question is hard to find.

Comment: @ChuckR I edited the title to make it more search-friedly.

Comment: On 20.04, this solution contradicts with the `gnome-tweaks` solution. While I have successfully disabled modal-attachment with the in the Tweaks GUI, this value in dconf-editor appears still enabled...

Comment: The correct dconf variable on 20.04 appears to be `org.gnome.mutter.attach-modal-dialogs`; (as per Anwar's answer) it at least appears to be in sync with my Tweak GUI.

Answer (score 17):

### For GNOME Shell

You can disable it in gnome-shell with a single command in the terminal. Open it with <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + T</kbd> shortcut and use the command below:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter attach-modal-dialogs false
```

You will get rid of that popup attachment.

On older versions of GNOME Shell was under `org.gnome.shell.overrides`, probably since [this issue](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701760).

### For Cinnamon

To disable the same on cinnamon, you need this command

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=bool /desktop/cinnamon/windows/attach_modal_dialogs false
```

You can use gconf-editor to do the same thing. Install it with `sudo apt-get install gconf-editor` command.

Answer (score 5):

The "design decision" is based on how macOS does it. It solves the problems with modal dialogs popping up without seeing to which program they belong to. The dialog should provide enough information to make your choice.

However, at least for gnome-shell you can change this behavior with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter attach-modal-dialogs false
```

Comment: An interesting compromise might have been to spawn the dialog within the parent window and allow it to be moved, but if you tried to fully drag it away, the parent would follow.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on Gnome 3.30.2 to allow detaching dialogs:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter attach-modal-dialogs false
```

or to re-attach them:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter attach-modal-dialogs true
```

and, to get the current setting:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.mutter attach-modal-dialogs
```

Answer (score 2):

This is by design in Cinnamon, as well as in gnome shell

This feature is for arranging  Modal Dialogs within their parent window, and can be disabled gnome shell by the use of `gconftool`. It can also be disabled in cinnamon.

This feature has also been seen in Mac OSX

Comment: So if the dialog hides information in the parent window, you're out of luck? Yet another stupid design decision by Ubuntu UI developers. :(

Comment: There should be a way of detaching the dialog like a Double click or something.

Comment: @JesperE - This isn't a decision made by the Ubuntu UI developers, but by the GNOME design team (and kept by the Cinnamon design team). In fact, vanilla Ubuntu has the "dialogs attached to windows" behavior turned off by default in 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 12.04 with Cinnamon, I used the gconf-editor method, but the path was org -> cinnamon -> overrides -> attach-modal-dialogs

Answer (score 0):

Cinnamon 4.8.4:

<kbd>Cinnamon settings</kbd> > <kbd>Windows</kbd> > Tab <kbd>Behavior</kbd> > Groupbox <kbd>Window focus</kbd> > <kbd>Attach dialog windows…</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found a [link with a way to fix this](https://gnomeshell.wordpress.com/2011/09/10/the-modal-windows-behavior/#more-297), this method is outdated in newer releases and gsettings should be used instead.

> In GNOME 3 the default modal dialog behavior is to attach the window so both the back and front window will be firmly attached together and dragging one of them will move even the other window, like if they became a single window.
>
> [image]
>
> This behavior can be changed to restore the old way the modal dialogs were treated in the previous GNOME releases. To **detach** the modal dialogs from the main window you will just need to execute the following command (in a single line) inside a terminal window:
>
> ```
> gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/shell/windows/attach_modal_dialogs false --type bool
> ```
>
> To **attach** the modal dialogs to the parent window you could execute:
>
> ```
> gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/shell/windows/attach_modal_dialogs true --type bool
> ```
>
> After issuing one of the previous commands you'll need to restart the GNOME Shell by logout the current session