# Allow Maximum Minimize modal window in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, window

Maximize Minimize not available

Running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

When using LibreOffice,
and go to the Options page,
it will not allow Maximize or Minimize (grayed-out).
The same in Nemo-Preferences,
and in KFind main page,
and in Ubuntu Software - About page.

Where might I go to make the change to allow Maximize/Minimize ?

Comment: "Modal" windows, if that's the right term, are usually hard-coded by the developers of the individual applications. And actions that can be done in normal windows may not be available in these modal windows. For example, the text in the Ubuntu Software - About window can't be copy/pasted elsewhere whereas the text in LibreOffice's Help > About page can be copied. I doubt very much that ordinary users can do anything about this except to file a feature request.

Comment: In case the reason for your asking the question is because the new window obscures part of the main window, look at https://askubuntu.com/a/972289/248158 for one way to deal with that.

Comment: A broader term would be dialogue windows. See https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/what-is-a-modal-dialog-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I won't be able to Maximize/Minimize the modal windows, since they are "hard-coded" that way.  Tk to DK Bose for sending me on the trail.

But that is when I am in the windows manager Gnome 3. So I found if I switch to Gnome Flashback (Compiz), or Mate, or Unity; Then I get buttons back that allow me to Max or Min.

And now I use Mate with Pantheon Panel,
and Compiz (Advanced CPU accelerated desktop effects),
and Open CCSM, Go to bottom to Window Management,
Make sure check is on Maximumize, Move Window, Place Window, and Resize Window.
Now all windows are able to be Max or Min or any size.