# What is the purpose of making the screen go "dark" when saving files or printing?

Tags: upgrade, printing

My "back screen" goes dark when I am saving a file or printing a document and the "front screen" will not move so I can read the headline of the document. I usually save files by the headline of the article and I used to be able to move the "front screen" off-center to re-read the headline for spelling and exact naming of the file. Why is this no longer a "feature" in Ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I move child windows without moving or minimizing parent in Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972276/how-do-i-move-child-windows-without-moving-or-minimizing-parent-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: Please note that in Ubuntu 18.10. the dialog window appears not longer to be treated as a child - hence the solution above will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the ability to move a dialog window around is with other features being removed with the present GNOME desktop. They still can be somewhat resized but having them centered appears to be hard coded.

To get the familiar behaviour back we can still install the Unity desktop while it is supported:

- [How can I make Ubuntu 18.04 / 18.10 desktop use Unity (be like Ubuntu 14.04)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040890/how-can-i-make-ubuntu-18-04-18-10-desktop-use-unity-be-like-ubuntu-14-04)

By this not only the old freely movable save dialogs will be back but also the windows button will be back to the left side:

[image]

Comment: Isn't [How do I move child windows without moving or minimizing parent in Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/q/972276/504066) the solution? Or did I misundertand the current question?

Comment: @PerlDuck: unfortunately does not work with 18.10. (may be that the save window is no longer a child...)